# Organising programmatically added views inside UIView with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, autolayout

I'm trying to rearrange some programmatically created views inside a UILabel.

```
numero.text = String(indexPath.row)
status.text = atividade?.status
nomeAtividade.text = atividade?.nome

numero.sizeToFit()
status.sizeToFit()
nomeAtividade.sizeToFit()

cellAtividade.textLabel?.addSubview(numero)
cellAtividade.textLabel?.addSubview(status)
cellAtividade.textLabel?.addSubview(nomeAtividade)
```

That's the code that creates the views and add 'em to the UILabel.

```
var viewsDictionary = ["numero":numero, "status":status, "nomeAtividade":nomeAtividade]

let view_constraint_V:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[numero]-[status]-[nomeAtividade]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

cellAtividade.textLabel?.addConstraints(view_constraint_V as [AnyObject])
```

And that's the one I'm using to create the Autolayout.

So, I'm getting autoLayout errors, "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" and I can imagine it is happening because I'm not using VFL right.

Comment: You didn't specify vertical constraints.

Comment: @TomášLinhart even with vertical constraints it seems to fail. 

`let view_constraint_V_toNomeAtividade:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[nomeAtividade]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)`

is how i'm doing it.